# Trying to Configure phpmyadmin file on WAMP, can't save it

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I've read tons of pages saying I need to change phpmyAdmin for WAMP. Followed instructions and changed the file, but when I go to save it says "ACCESS DENIED". Apparently I don't have permission to save a file on my own computer.

Has anyone else had this same problem?

Comment: Updating phpMyAdmin is not just about changing one file. Which instructions did you follow?

Comment: Here's the main installation instructions I'm following: http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/install-wordpress-on-your-computer-using-wampserver/

Comment: And here's the phpadmin file editing instructions: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,88798,117589

Comment: You get an error, saving httpd.conf? Which Windows version?

Answer (score 0):

Without you being more specific about what you are doing it's hard to help, but my guess is you need to run whatever text editor you're using as Administrator.

Right click on a Notepad (or whatever text editor) and hit Run as Administrator, then hit Open and navigate to the file.  It should allow you to save it that way.

Also it goes without saying you should turn WAMP server off before editing anything.